# Login form with SQL Server database in asp.net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a login system in ASP.net. It shows no error, but still doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
SqlConnection connectionstring = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;User Id=AMS; Password = password; ");

public void LoadData() //<-- call this when the button is pressed
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT `Username`, `Password` FROM `LoginData` WHERE `Username` = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND `Password` = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'", connectionstring);

        SqlDataReader myReader;
        connectionstring.Open();

        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Login successful!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),"ServerControlScript", script, true);
            connectionstring.Close();
        }
        else if (count == 0)
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Login Failed!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),"ServerControlScript", script, true);
            connectionstring.Close();
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        connectionstring.Close();
    }
}
```

It's simply not working. And I don't know why.

This is the code for the button in CSS

```
#Button1{

background-color: #0066CC;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
margin-right: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 15px;
font-size: 14px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 18px;
z-index: 1;

position: absolute;
top: 203px;
left: 383px;
width: 130px;
}
```

and this is in the asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

It shows no error, or anything, just refreshes the page when I click the button.
What is the problem? I am unable to find it. Maybe is in the SQL connection string?

EDIT: suggested by Steve to remove the try/catch

This is the error I get

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: Please remove the try/catch and tell us what is the error message raised by your code. Do not write empty try/catch. They just hides problem, don't solve them

Comment: Where is your button click event ? Please write full code

Comment: @Steve yes, that was hiding the error. I edited it and under it show the error it shows.

Comment: So it seems that you don't have an instance of SQLEXPRESS on your local machine. Are you able to connect to this instance using Sql Server Management Studio? Do you have enabled the required protocols (TCP) with the Sql Server Configuration Tools?

Comment: Not related to the question but use parameterized query to be safe from SQL Injections. SQL injections: http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection and How to execute a Parameterized Query https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @M.Raees I think that I got an error with the SQLconnection. where I specify the error.

Comment: and when you fix your connection problem your query will fail because column names do not get surrounded by quotes, or ticks.

Comment: @Crowcoder and what do you suggest? how can I fix that?

Comment: like this: `"SELECT Username, ....`, no tick marks around Username, etc.

Comment: @BerGEX As Steve suggested, make sure that you have an instance of SQLExpress on your machine. That could be the issue with the SQL connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the error caused by the invalid configuration of Sql Server Express (probably the required protocol is not enabled (TCP) you should also note that 
Sql Server doesn't use the backticks around the field names and tablenames. If it is necessary to have a distinction between field names and  reserved words Sql Server uses the square brackets.

Said that your code should be rewritten to use parameters and not a string concatenation. String concatenation is well know as a wrong way to build queries because it is easy to introduce bugs and allowing Sql Injection attacks

```
public void LoadData() 
{

    string cmdText = @"SELECT 1 FROM LoginData 
                       WHERE Username = @name AND AND Password = @pass";

    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    using(SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
    {
       SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
       SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
       cnn.Open();
       using(myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
       {
           // No need to read anything. If your reader has rows then
           // the user and its password exists 
           // (you don't allow two users have the same name right?)
           if(myReader.HasRows)
           {
             string script = "alert(\"Login successful!\");";
             ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),"ServerControlScript", script, true);
           }
           else
           {
              string script = "alert(\"Login Failed!\");";
              ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),"ServerControlScript", script, true);
           }
      }         
   }
}
```

Notice that I have used the using statement around the disposable objects to be sure that these objects are closed and disposed also in case of exceptions.

Another thing to do is to use TrustedConnection=True to use Windows Authentication against your database server and not needing a specific user to log in. Of course this will change in case you need to deploy your program to a customer pc and depends on the customer requirements.

Comment: thanks for the code. but I am getting a weird error.
"Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''
kinda confused by this, tried to create 2 other accounts and still no result

Comment: I suggest you give the command parameters or OP will be reporting another problem.

Comment: @Crowcoder of course. In a bit of hurry forget about those.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is `OnClick="Button1_Click"`.
are you sure you've called the `LoadData` method (in event `Button1_Click`, maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an exception being thrown by `SqlConnection`. Add a message to your `catch`:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string script = String.Format("alert('Error occured creating user. Exception message: {0}');", ex.Message);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),"ServerControlScript", script, true);
    connectionstring.Close();
}
```